# Explanation of the ending of the episode "Kafkaesque" (S03E09)

Tags: plot-explanation, breaking-bad, dialogue

At the end of the *Breaking Bad* episode "Kafkaesque" (S03E09) Skyler says to Walt when talking about Hank (who is in the hospital recovering from his gunshot wounds at the hands of the cartel hit men), "Somehow, something tells me that Hank is here because of you and I'm not forgetting that." They don't show her face while she says it or after. So did she mean:

A: She thinks the reason Hank was attacked and thus is in the hospital has something to do with Walt, or

B: she thinks Walt had something to do with the phone call that warned Hank he was about to be attacked and thus thinks Walt is the reason Hank is alive and not dead.

I think A but am not positive. Walt's expression after she says it could fit either option.

Answer (score 9):

The best explanation is the first one. Walt still doesn't want to admit that he constitutes a danger to the family (including his bother in law Hank). And he surely doesn't want to scare Skyler. Much as Walt might want to let Skyler know he did something to protect the family, he can't do this without revealing the depths to which he has already gone and the danger he has exposed them to.

The only way the second,  more convoluted explanation could be true would be if Skyler already knew all the details of Walt's activities and thought him capable of machiavellian levels of manipulation. I don't think she achieves that until sometime in season 4.

Answer (score 0):

On the one hand, option A makes sense "Hank is in the hospital because of Walter" but the truth is that my first thought (until even watching the series for a second time) was option B "Hank is here with us alive because of you and that is why I am thinking more and more of coming back to you and helping you". She seemed calm when saying that and not angry as option A would suggest. The line before that was "I learned from the best" so I do not see how it would be possible from changing from positive to negative thoughts so fast.

Anyway, that is Breaking bad's beauty, there is always a debate

Comment: Well, *"I learned from the best"* was not really a compliment, given that it was *lying* she meant to have learned from him. And I think she said that in the same bitter/cynical way as many other little side attacks she gave her husband. So I wouldn't interpret too many positive feelings into calmness from her side.